# Passing persistent values into a class

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

Using Python 2.7 and Tkinter in Linux Mint 'Mate' 17 environment

I'm completely new to OOP and don't understand how to pass persistent values into a class instance; in this code a "global not defined" error is generated when I use Pin_ID at lines 20 and 22:

```
 1  #!/usr/bin/env python
 2  import Tkinter as tk
 3
 4  root = tk.Tk()
 5
 6  class cbClass:
 7    def __init__(self, Pin_ID):
 8      self.cb_Txt=tk.StringVar()
 9      self.cb_Txt.set("Pin " + Pin_ID + " OFF")
10      self.cb_Var = tk.IntVar()
11      cb = tk.Checkbutton(
12        root,
13        textvariable=self.cb_Txt,
14        variable=self.cb_Var,
15        command=self.cbTest)
16      cb.pack()
17
18    def cbTest(self):
19      if self.cb_Var.get():
20        self.cb_Txt.set("Pin " + Pin_ID + " ON")
21      else:
22        self.cb_Txt.set("Pin " + Pin_ID + " OFF")
23
24  c1 = cbClass("8")
25  c2 = cbClass("E")
26  root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think, it is because of Pin_ID, you have Pin_ID as parameter in your `_init_` function but not in `cbTest`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to save `PinID` in a class instance variable. This is done in `__init__` with

```
self.PinID = PinID
```

and in `cbTest`, you would access with `self.PinID` rather than just `PinID`

Comment: Thanks Tommy for such a prompt and helpful answer.  I wonder why you can't just pass a value in the class definition, as in class cbClass (Pin_ID), and use that value globally within the class?

Comment: that's kind of what happens when you add it to `self` since the object's instance data and methods are maintained in `self` and is implicitly passed to all methods of the class. You could probably achieve a global definition by using the `global` keyword, but that would be hackish and could adversely affect other things in the namespace. `self` is the way to go when maintaining instance-specific data in a class

Answer (score 5):

If you want to remember a constructor argument's value, you need to save it as a class instance attribute, using `self`, as already mentioned. More fundamentally what needs improvement is your GUI button design and related use of the `Tkinter` module.

Here's an example of a more typical way to accomplish what I think you're trying to do. It changes the GUI by removing the redundancy of having a `CheckButton`'s state represented by both whether it's checkmarked *and* what's displayed as its label (i.e. if it's checked, it's ON).

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

class cbClass:
    def __init__(self, PinID):
        self.PinID = "Pin " + PinID
        self.cbTxt = tk.StringVar()
        self.cbTxt.set(self.PinID)
        self.cb = tk.Checkbutton(root,
                                 text=self.PinID,
                                 variable=self.cbTxt,
                                 onvalue="ON", offvalue="OFF",
                                 command=self.cbTest)
        self.cb.pack()

    def cbTest(self):
        """ Called when checkbutton state is changed. """
        print("{} variable is now {}".format(self.PinID, self.cbTxt.get()))

c1 = cbClass("8")
c2 = cbClass("E")
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tommy:  by adding this line in the -init-:

```
 self.Pin_ID = Pin_ID
```

and by preferencing references elsewhere with self., as in:

```
 self.cb_Txt.set ("Pin " + self.Pin_ID + " ON")
```

I was able to pass the value through.

Comment: In your original post, the problem was the scope of that name, it only *existed* within ```__init__```, the block it was defined in.   The solution was to make it am attribute of the class instance.  Here are are couple of references - [9.2. Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces),  - [4.1. Naming and binding](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding).